# Issue Closing Then Reopening Anaconda Prompt After Installation

Tags: anaconda

I just installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 on my laptop running 64 bit windows 8.

Once I finish installing Anaconda I go to open the Anaconda prompt and then I run conda update --all. This runs seemingly fine. When it's done running I close the prompt by hitting the close button in the upper right corner.

The issue comes in when I then go to open a new Anaconda prompt. I go to my start menu and open a new prompt. However, instead of the prompt that opened immediately after installing Anaconda I get a command window with these three lines:

> >was unexpected at this time.
>
> PATH > @IF NOT ""=="" @chcp > NUL
>
> PATH >

An error seems to happen when I try to open my Anaconda prompt and then my path gets changed back to my default non-Anaconda command prompt path.

Could someone provide any help with this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue. I have a habit of opening Jupyter notebook through anaconda prompt which I cannot do now. Fortunately, the jupyter notebook is opening through Anaconda navigator. Not sure what will I do to use "conda" commands until this issue is solved

Comment: I had to uninstall Anaconda2 and reinstall the latest version and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, except that my installation is already 2 months old, suddenly noticing this today.
Olivier.

Answer (score 0):

Open the anaconda prompt and change the anaconda prompt directory to Anaconda/Scripts and then you can use the conda commands.